# AVQueuePlayer status access errors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer

I am trying to figure out `obj-c/cocoa touch` and the `AVPlayer` in particular. I can build and play an `AVQueuePlayer` without any problem.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject: [self buildPlayerItem:@"http://<some url>first.mp3"]];
[items addObject: [self buildPlayerItem:@"http://<some url>second.mp3"]];

self.queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:items];
```

I can call play, pause, `advanceToNextItem` and `currentItem` on `self.queuePlayer`, but any call to `[self.queuePlayer status]` method or attempt to access the `self.queuePlayer.status` property causes the app to throw a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. I get the same issue trying to get the status of the queuePlayer's currentItem.

My understanding is that this error indicates that I am trying to access a property on an object that has been freed, but

1) I am using ARC 
2) it seems impossible that self.queuePlayer hasn't been freed, since I can call play on it,and 
3) status is a property of self.queuePlayer, not a property in one of my own classes, so presumably something in the AVQueuePlayer implementation is managing the status variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the status property of `AVPlayer` is an int...I had assumed it was a `NSString` or something more complicated. So the problem was not referencing a freed object, but printing an int with %@.